# webbrowser control login problem with password

Tags: vb.net

I am using webbrowser control for automate login in https://www.itslb.com/tms/ website i have written code also but password input box doesnt hold any value username hold so could anyone tell me why happen this
my code like below

```
Dim frmform As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("aspnetForm")
frmform.All("ctl00_lnkLogin").InvokeMember("Click")

frmform.All("ctl00_txtUserName").SetAttribute("value", sUserID)
frmform.All("ctl00_txtPassword").SetAttribute("value", sPWD)
frmform.GetElementsByTagName("select")(0).Document.GetElementsByTagName("option")(1).SetAttribute("selected", "true")

'frmform.All("ctl00$cboTerminal").InvokeMember("SelectedIndexChanged")
'frmform.GetElementsByTagName("select")(0).Document.GetElementsByTagName("option")(1).SetAttribute("selected", "true")
frmform.All("ctl00_btnLogin").Enabled = True
frmform.All("ctl00_btnLogin").InvokeMember("Submit")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When posting code, please mark it up (you can do this by indenting the code manually, or highlighting it and pressing the `{}` button)

Answer (score 0):

I have used InnerText successfully for login boxes before(that is what you would use in a regular COM method, anyway):
I am guessing that sPWD is a var for your password, and that "ctl00_txtPassword" is the id for your password box.

```
whatbrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_txtPassword").InnerText = sPWD
```

You might also try this:

```
frmform.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_txtPassword").SetAttribute("value", sPWD)
```